# How do I prevent the line break on resizing?

Tags: html, css

How do I prevent the line break on resizing?

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left </div>
    <div class="right">Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right</div>
</div>
```

I want both divs side by side whatever window width is set...

```
.wrapper {
    max-width: 990px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
.left {
    float: left;
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m5d9jkxq/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Will ellipsis work for you?

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    max-width: 990px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:50%
}
.right {
    float: right;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:50%;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/m5d9jkxq/2/

Answer (score 0):

You did not describe the expected behavior of the 'left' and 'right' div when the window size is not enough to show them all.

So below is a solution based on 'flexbox' in CSS3.

```
.wrapper {
    max-width: 990px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.left {
}

.right {
}
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lotabout/m5d9jkxq/3/)

For more information about how flexbox works, please check [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

Two issues you're seeing if you want all of that on one line always. First off is that float left and right will still bump into each other and push the lower one down to the next line. Second issue is if you just set a width, your text will wrap to the next line if it's too long.

So, to fix the first part set a max-width - this prevents the divs from hitting each other. This of course is the second issue, so to correct it set white-space to nowrap so the text is all always on only one line. Then overflow hidden to hide any overlap.

```
.wrapper div{
    max-width: 50%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/m5d9jkxq/4/

If you just want the divs side by side and don't care about the one line piece, simply leave it at the max-width 50%:

```
.wrapper div{
    max-width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

without overlapping words

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 990px;
  width:100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align:center;
}
.left {
  display: inline;
}
.right {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left</div>
  <div class="right">Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right</div>
  </div
```

---

if you are okay with overlapping words,

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 990px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left</div>
  <div class="right">Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind about overlapping, just change your CSS to:

```
.left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
}

.right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v7vx2wjd/